# Is it possible to make the background of an android app into a animated background like a gif?

Tags: android, animation, gif, animated, android-background

I don't mean make a gif into a background just a background that moves. Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean like a live wallpaper?

Answer (score 2):

GIFs do not work on the Android framework like people are used to.
Instead of using GIFs, try the following to animate a background:

1. Get a reference to the widget whose background you want to be animated. For example `TextView tv;`
2. Remove content so that only the background is visible.  `tv.setText("")`
3. Set custom background to your view. `tv.setBackground("Background here")`
4. Set an animation to your view `tv.setAnimation(myAnimation)`
5. Animate your view `tv.startAnimation();`

And there you go. There are many examples and resources about animations in the official documentation.